# Get value from kivy text input in kv during build

Tags: python, kivy

I have three questions/problems:

1. given below configuration of app/app kv file why do I have to call self.build() in ButtonsFactory class. If i remove it, i get black screen, probably because there is no root element in kv file, yet if i tried making MainView root element i end up with black screen as well.
2. second question, is it possible to set in my someapp.kv file minimum height for custom buttons? They should never be less than X.
3. last but for me **most important** why I am unable to get text property of TextInput from kv file, in class function get_list_of_files()? What would be best way to fix this? Global variable which hardcode this value in python code? Moving Builder before python code (embedd kv as string)?
4. last question...buttons "fill" scrollview_id instead of preserve size and be scrollable inside this view, I'd like them to stop self adjusting size.

someapp.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
# views
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
# layouts
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

import os

# defined in kv file.
class HeaderContainer(BoxLayout): pass
class ButtonsContainer(BoxLayout): pass
class MainView(ModalView): pass

class ButtonsFactory(BoxLayout):
    target_location = StringProperty(None)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ButtonsFactory, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.build() # Question 1: is that neccessary? (i think not, but black screen without it, why?)

    def build(self):
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        for file_name in self.get_list_of_files():
            btn = Factory.CustomButton()
            with open(file_name, 'r') as test_file:
                btn.file_name = test_file.readline().strip()[1:20]
            btn.nice_name = file_name  # Question 2: is it possible to set minimum height for kivy button? (havent found in api)
            self.add_widget(btn)
        # print ("1.!!!!!!", self.target_location) == NONE
    @classmethod
    def get_list_of_files(cls):
        # print "2.!!!!!!", repr(cls.target_location) == <kivy.properties.StringProperty object at 0x7f1dd7596e20> 
        dir_ = "/tmp" #dir_ = cls.target_location
        try:
            files = [os.path.join(dir_, name) for name in os.listdir(dir_)
                     if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_, name))]
        except (OSError, IOError):
            files = []
        return files

class SomeApp(App):
    def on_pause(self):
        pass
    def on_resume(self):
        pass
    def build(self):
        return MainView()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SomeApp().run()
```

and someapp.kv file

```
#:kivy 1.8.0
#:import platform platform

<CustomButton@Button>:
    file_name: ''
    nice_name: ''
    text: root.nice_name + "\n" + root.file_name
    halign:'center'
    size_hint:(1, 0.1)

<HeaderContainer>:
    id: header_layout
    size_hint:(1, 0.1)
    orientation:'horizontal'
    # 2-nd-try # target_location: textinput_target_location.text
    # I was trying here to pass by ObjectProperty (or StringProperty) but unfortunately failed.
    TextInput:
        size_hint:(0.7, 1)
        id: textinput_target_location
        multiline: False
        hint_text: "path where stress files are stored, default /sdcard/appdir"
        text: "/tmp" if platform.machine() in ["x86_64", "i686", "i386"] else "/sdcard/appdir/"  # arm "arm7l", but also other arm's
        #on_text: my_callback_to_reload_dir_contents()
    Button:
        size_hint:(0.2, 1)
        id: read_target_location
        text: "read target_location directory"
        #on_release: my_callback_to_reload_dir_contents()

<ButtonsContainer>:
    size_hint:(1, 0.9)
    orientation:'vertical'
    ScrollView:
        id: scrollview_id
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ButtonsFactory


<MainView>:
    BoxLayout:
        # 1-st-try # target_location: HeaderContainer.target_location
        id: main_layout
        padding:10
        spacing: 5
        orientation:'vertical'
        HeaderContainer
        # n-th-try # target_location: HeaderContainer.target_location
        ButtonsContainer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to address your questions:

**1)** Looking at your code, the `ButtonsFactory` is just a `BoxLayout`, which is a container for holding other widgets.  The `self.build` function creates `CustomButton` widgets and puts them in the container.  If you don't call `self.build`, nothing gets added to the container and you have an empty (blank) `BoxLayout`.

**2)** This is a little more complicated as the hight is usually controlled by what container is holding your widget.  You can manually set height of widgets by setting the `size_hint` property to `None` and specifying the height.

**3)** I would never use global variables if they can be avoided.  In this case, if all you need is access to the text content of the TextInput, I would bind it to a `StringProperty` attached to a widget you can access or the App object itself (which can be accessed anywhere in .kv as `app.<property>`.

**4)** Again, the height is controlled by the container the widgets are in (a `BoxLayout`).  You can manually control their size by setting `size_hint` to None on the widgets.

Another problem is that you are putting a `BoxLayout` (your `ButtonsFactory`) inside a `ScrollViewer`.  The `BoxLayout` will resize itself to fit exactly inside the `ScrollViewer` so it will not scroll.  You will need to override this behavior by clearing `size_hint`.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699053/adding-scrollbar-to-boxlayout-in-kivy) for details.

Comment: first of all thank You for interest and help. Moving on, 1. i understand, but i thought that whole point is that Kivy calls build itself ? Maybe it is valid only for widgets though. 2. and 4. understood. 3. Well, that's where the problem is. As You probably noticed, I've tried to set and use this property, but only way i was able to do it was to set it as app.property, and modify (set default) in build function. I don't think this is great solution, but still, it works and advice was tremendous help.

Comment: Sure thing.  The ```build``` function you are thinking of is the ```App.build```, which kivy calls to get the root widget for the application.